# How can I monitor the wireless signal level and frequency and log it in csv format?

Tags: command-line, wireless, text-processing

I want to run the command `iw dev wlan0 link` continuously every second and save the output into a `csv` file.

I am using the following command:

```bsh
while sleep 1; do
  iw dev wlan0 link | grep 'freq:\|signal' | awk '{printf "%s ", $2, $3}' >> log.csv
done
```

But the output is saved in `log.csv` in the following way:

```
2412 -41 2412 -42 2412 -45 2412 -43
```

I want the output to be saved in a way where the two fields are separated by comma (so they will be displayed in separate columns in editors such as MS Excel) and each run into a new line. The `log.csv` shall look like this (You can ignore the labels, they are only for explanation):

```
Signal  Frequency
-41     2412
-42     2412
-45     2412
-43     2412
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When running `iw help` you see a warning:

> Do **not** screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable.

There are **two sections** below: First a solution to your problem avoiding `iw` and second an answer to your question. Both work with traditional `awk` as well as (the default) `GNU Awk`.

## Solution to your problem

I'd use `iwconfig` instead of `iw`:

```bash
while sleep 1; do
  iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ :=]+' '/Freq/{gsub("\\.","");f=$5}/Signal/{s=$7}END{print s","f}'
done >>log.csv
```

#### Output

```
$ iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ :=]+' '/Freq/{gsub("\\.","");f=$5}/Signal/{s=$7}END{print s","f}'
-44,2412
```

#### Notes

I got confused whether you want the values separated by `,` or rather a tab (which would be `\t`), I chose `,` without and surrounding spaces here. If that's not what you wanted just change `s","f` accordingly, `s` is the `Signal` and `f` the `Frequency` value there.
I also moved the redirection, this way the file doesn't have to be opened on each run but just once.

#### Explanations of the `awk` part

- `-F'[ :=]+'` – sets a different field delimiter, here to one or more (`+`) of the three characters enclosed in square brackets
- `/Freq/{gsub("\\.","");f=$5}` – in the line(s) with “Freq”, replace every dot by nothing (because the frequency in the `iwconfig` output uses a dot as the thousands separator) and save the content of the fifth column in variable `f`
- `/Signal/{s=$7}` – in the line(s) with “Signal”, save the content of the seventh column in variable `s`
- `END{print s","f}` – after processing the input, `print` the variables `s` and `f` with a literal comma between them

## Answer to your question

```bash
while sleep 1; do
  iw dev wlan0 link | awk '/freq/{f=$2};/signal/{s=$2}END{print s","f}'
done >>log.csv
```

#### Output

```
$ iw dev wlan0 link | awk '/freq/{f=$2};/signal/{s=$2}END{print s","f}'
-43,2412
```

#### Explanations of the `awk` part

- `/freq/{f=$2}` – in the line(s) with `freq`, save the second column (space separated) in variable `f`
- `/signal/{s=$2}` – in the line(s) with `signal`, save the second column in variable `s`
- `END{print s","f}` – after processing the input, `print` the variables `s` and `f` with a literal comma between them